# How to call a php script using javascript and ajax?

Tags: php, html, ajax, onclick

i have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doSomething() {
  $.get("supcont.php");
  return false;
}
</script>
```

an i want to call this function when clicking on an img so i used this

```
<a href="#" onclick="doSomething();">
  <img src="photo/suppc.png" width="295" height="36" href="" target="fenetreA"/>
</a>
```

but this doesn't work, is ther any one that can help me

Comment: how are you initiating this code?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: it works when i call an alert but when i use $.get("supcont.php"); it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function () {
    $('img').live('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url:"supcont.php",
            success:function (res) {
                alert(res);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this anywhere:

```
<img id="img1" src="photo/suppc.png" width="295" height="36"    href="" target="fenetreA"/>
```

Place this after you include JQuery.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#img1").click(function(){
       $.get("supcont.php");
    });
});
</script>
```

More info here : http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

Check [w3schools website](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp). Much helpful to you regarding this.